# Is call stack always used when running recursive functions

Tags: python

The following recursive function creates a frame on the call stack and then once the base case is reached all results are popped of the stack:

```
def subL(L):
    x=len(L)
    if x==1:
        return L
    else:
        subL(L[:x-1])
        print(L[:x-1]) #<<onto the call stack
```

---

```
>>> j=[2,5,99,31,14,5]
>>> subL(j)

[2]
[2, 5]
[2, 5, 99]
[2, 5, 99, 31]
[2, 5, 99, 31, 14]
```

I thought all recursive functions used the call stack but does the following? If I place the recursive call at the end of the script then is the call stack not required?

```
def subLx(L):
    x=len(L)
    if x==1:
        return L
    else:
        print(L[:x-1]) #runs each time it is called so call stack not required?
        subLx(L[:x-1])
```

---

```
>>> q=[2,5,99,31,14,5]
>>> subLx(q)

[2, 5, 99, 31, 14]
[2, 5, 99, 31]
[2, 5, 99]
[2, 5]
[2]
```

Comment: Your second code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Is Tail Call Optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't see how that is a duplicate: although this question is indeed about TCO, it is specifically about Python - which *doesn't* do TCO.

Comment: @JakobBowyer ....that is the snippet > the input > the output: works fine on my machine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about Tail Call Optimization. Python does not do this optimization: all function calls allocate a new stack. That's why it's relatively easy to reach the recursion limit in Python, even with tail calls.

Comment: +1 The reference added to my OP is useful as this concept is new to me but seems totally relevent. So effectively if a langauge implements it then best to try and avoid using the call stack?